# IBM MobileFirst adapter call 404

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-console

With MobileFirst 7.0 over Liberty Profile, using Platform Operations Console, I cant connect to adapters in preview.

This is the error in messages.log
    [28/04/15 10:59:34:624 CEST] 00000026 org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor             I The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (404 - Not Found) with message 'null' while processing POST request sent to http://server1.domain.local:9080/app1/authorization/v1/clients/preview

The chrome debugger shows this network request:
Request URL: http://server1.domain.local:9080/app1/authorization/v1/clients/preview
StatusCode: 404 Not Found

I've tried deleting security in adapter's xml configuration.

Comment: can you provide the Server logs.

Comment: messages.log:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxAEyIioPI2Yb2k3TExza2U1dlE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Preview is not meant to work in a production environment, however the preview button was still there in the GM release of MFPF 7.0.

I think you might have hit APAR PI37266:

> MFP OPERATIONS CONSOLE: PREVIEW OF COMMON RESOURCES BUTTON MUST BE
>   HIDDEN IN PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT

So, you should update your installation to the latest available 7.0 iFix, where the preview button is no longer available. To get the latest iFIx, you need to login to the IBM Fix Central website and search for "mobilefirst platform" to get the latest.